# Class import and assignment in Python

Tags: python, class, module

If I am creating a class below, can someone please explain the proper way to create the instance and also pass in the arguments.  I though that I would be able to pass in the initial arguments at time of initiation but cannot seem to get this to work.  Below is an example of the class:

```
Class Course(object):
    """
    Represents a University course
    """

    def _init_(self, name, teacher, description):
        self.name = name
        self.teacher= price
        self.description = description

    def _str_(self):
        return "{name} ({desc}): {teacher:}".format(name=self.name,
                desc=self.description, teacher=self.teacher)
```

So in my program I'd like to create an instance which I though I do by using something like `class = Course()`.

But isn't there a way to initiate the 3 variables at the same time?  Something along the lines of `class('Math101', 'Dr. Know Nothing', 'Learning is Fun')`  ?

Then I can just `print class` and get my desired output string as defined from within the class?  I might be missing an import somewhere which is also confusing to me if I need to import modules or with a class all I need to do is the initial `class = Course()` ?

Comment: Change `_init_` to `__init__`.(Double underscores)

Comment: +1. Also, `class` is a language keyword, so you really shouldn't use it as a variable name. And it has a lowercase 'C' when you use it for what is was meant for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare **[special methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)** *with double underscores*: `__init__`, not `_init_`. And then, when creating an object, you have to pass the arguments like: `course1 = Course(...parameters...)`:

```
class Course(object):
    """
    Represents a University course
    """
    def __init__(self, name, teacher, description):
        self.name = name
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.description = description

    def __str__(self):
        return "{name} ({desc}): {teacher:}".format(name = self.name,
                desc = self.description, teacher = self.teacher)

course1 = Course('Math101', 'Dr. Know Nothing', 'Learning is Fun')
print course1
```

**Output:**

```
Math101 (Learning is Fun): Dr. Know Nothing
```

**Notes:**

- The Python keyword to create a class is `class`, not `Class`. Python is case-sensitive for keywords.
- You were assigning `price` to `self.teacher`, which would lead in an error because `price` is not declared anywhere. I think it's just a typo. You may use `self.teacher = teacher` instead.
- You **must not** use Python keywords (reserved names) as name of variables, because if you did, you would be *hiding* those keywords, which would lead into problems.

Comment: Ahh, missed some basics here.  When I try course1= Course("paramaters"), I've been getting 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable'    Am I missing an import?  Many thanks!

Comment: Are you getting this error from running the code I provided? Or you are trying something else?

Comment: I used your fixed code and saved file as Course.py   From the shell I then get this error after I import Course.   When I enter 'Course' into the shell I get '<module 'Course' from 'Course.py'>'  So I think I am missing something even further basic.

Comment: Just change the name of the file or the name of the class. When you import a file with the same name of a class. Python will use just one, maybe the one you didn't expected to use. (In your case it's using the file)

Comment: Thank you @Christian.  The naming convention was it.  Changed file name to 'Lesson' and then was able to 'from Lesson import Course' and works.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to double your underscores:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    // whatever

def __str__(self, ...):
    // whatever
```

and lowercase your `Class`: `class Course` instead of `Class Course`.

Now you can use your class like this:

```
course = Course('Math101', 'Dr. Know Nothing', 'Learning is Fun') 
print course
```